# ColdFusion session maintains with browser cookie disabled?

Tags: coldfusion

Is there anyway to make the ColdFusion application to maintain its session, even if the browser cookie has been disabled ?

**NOTE :** I don't want to use `addtoken="true"` in `<cflocation/>` tags. I mean I don't want to use the session token in the URL.

Comment: A JEE server cannot maintain session state without either cookies _or_ passing the identifiers in the URL. It needs one of them to identify the client.

Comment: Okay, But passing the identifiers in URL is not secure right?.  If some users facing the login problem, due to disabling cookie on their browsers means, we need to ask them to enable cookies on their browsers.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yeah already googled, most sources said that to use the session tokens in the URL, if we don't want to set in cookies.

Comment: Our major application requires cookies so we do a check right off the bat.  If cookies are disabled, the user gets a message explaining why they can't access the application.  Mind you, this is an intranet situation so it's not costing us any potential sales.

Comment: @RajeshManilal yes. Typically you do not want to pass session identifiers in the URL. Read this for more - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Management_Implementation  I think it is fine to require users to enable cookies for your site. After all, you are helping to protect _their_ session with your servers. If they have cookies disabled I suspect they have issues navigating the web today. More so if they disable JavaScript as well.

Comment: yeah Thanks @DanBracuk and Miguel-F for your clarifications. I know that we can handle this through cookies or URL parameters, but just want to ensure that is there any other way which I may not know. Anyway thanks again.